# How to use string[] in which I added data from my database in Alert Dialog.Builder?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-alertdialog

```
// My get All Function
 Cursor getAll()
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+RouteTableID+" as _id, "+RouteName+" from "+RouteTable,new      String [] {});
     return cur;
 }


// Retrieving Data From Database and Store in item String[]
    String item[] = new String[100];
    int i=0;
    Cursor c = db.getAll();
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
      item[i] = c.getString(1);
      c.moveToNext();
      i++;
    }
```

And Now I want to use this string[] item in my Alert Dailog like this:

```
builder1.setCancelable(false);
myDialog1 = builder1.create();
builder1.setItems(item, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
});
```

And I used it as when I press the button, the Dialog appears.

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myDialog1.show();
        }
    });
```

But it gives an error that Unfortunately your_App has stopped when I click On Button.

And when I just declare the string[] like String[] item[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
and then pass this string to alertdialog, it runs perfectly fine.

The Logcat window is:

```
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765): Process: com.techblogon.loginexample, PID: 1765
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362) 
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2240)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)  
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1088)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-23 07:14:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1765):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a String array of size 100, which is most probably not the exact number of elements in the `Cursor` object. Therefore, some of this elements will probably be null and hence cause the `NullPointerException`

You should probably initialize it like this:

```
Cursor c = db.getAll();
String item[] = new String[c.getCount()];
```